# Removing variables from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following php coding to randomly select a video from a long list of video ID's. What I want to do is remove the video ID from the array after the video has been watched. I should be more specific. There are 256 video ID's within the array. When the page loads It selects a video ID at random, and ques the video. What I want to happen is after that video has been watched, and the user pushes my "random" button. The video that was just watched is removed from the array, and another one, at random, is selected. I don't want the video ID to be permanently removed from the array, but temporarily removed so they don't get the same video at random.

For reference, the site is http://www.grindhousegarage.com

```
<?php
$videolist = array('y9TAeIk1wCs', '6kApARt4Mds', '4Jgc-aolx5M', 'tHWAoKzHut8', 'USSnC-1Oq2g', 'H9rfvs-Memw', '2OMFSX3sJQw', 'Pt-EipwlWQ0', 'qxLSZFO-wTI', 'BsbpN9wXf6k', 'ztEIkFQrj28', 'AVi6eukVPOw', 'mzBCnBG_HqY', '8e9ZDYQSxG4', '6sUgC5BWU10', 'JTlFMvxj8_Q', 'uE6Z1nBqLwo', 'z3Fg_K08YIA', 'GqWn_lsjOV0', 'uF8rq8023AA', 'Pn9nXSq5p8I', 'I1zhZMN96Xw', '5X0z0uCALKU', 'KFbmYyVcaeQ', 'tl9JgWzrpT0', 'MbpqcEzzB5c', 'rykGcFPLyxA', 'X4wRgNR8QIo', 'yqGgZJcfNlQ', 'EtrkMmqv1eQ', '1v0TMGFRpgQ', 't4ONk88Xln4', '5pjjuFT6QF4', 'IZjmGDLyM9Q', 'LNfvLtfjfhY', 'qTGN0dcNhqk', '5FXhbltanB0', 'MVk7rnI8v9k', 'iyycwz_Msy0', 'F3nHEOXoh7c', 'mqFWrGKLb4E', 'bVxLB65faIY', 'ereen__ld8g', 'Kl1QO7ljUIQ', '5zkCnHUnoYY', 'nRmpgI-_a-c', 'XLsfs2YNgAE', 'AQ2ec7daCYY', 'rRstqUQhQ48', 'AleCmkfCbJ4', 'Hl8-jS26XaM', 'KFbmYyVcaeQ', 'UTDgaVL5zxw', 'GZ5paTwRA_k', 'YOSWA9OBjls', 'hutsOBSINQw', 'kAv5S-48i-E', 'n0N4yen5ilg', '_cv1zGmnoVs', '3R0ye-flA7I', 'xSJvlQqrwx4', 'DCVs532r4HY', 'DCVs532r4HY', '_dLpzmEH8nI', '1ujJ5NN5FaM', 'vbIpdBbiybM', 'JtR562QHTT4', '30-O8U4kfjk', 'BtR6IrvxeFs', 'i3i8krPi7cg', 'D5yDKqWX1Uo', 'YJzIvr5u2n0', '0xD8AE8ZcpA', '53IeDxWoWm0', 'F9RWr3fqxdg', 'iLx1I7rqo-k', 'waUk0igDAEA', 'w5fc43O3ynE', 'LHkLtLVSGVs', 'gTZPOh21q2Q', 'vDvv0dwxoYk', '6vBAwc23sD8', '8EtfOdRRxTc', 'ZzaIJfFEyN0', 'hcITGTx6SbI', '8iRoamv2qvQ', '6wj_36cm6Nc', 'u0KNXj-noHE', 'ymHZnu0L6LU', 'H8TWgOHWeig', 'U-ZiDMhFmYg', 'QjQsQXZgywA', 'maXcwJKSTCw', 'bvWw5tmQ_pw', 'r0JVZvvpU6E', '5pjjuFT6QF4', 'pbhmFfHpX5M', 'kBvR4pxNHO4', 'r5U7F0NJ1RQ', 'FrwAJWGYdqY', 'pG--yUNkdm4', 'AVj4z_k0G-s', 'wQzWAX8xJhQ', 'q8DVV3vBlzk', 'xKmPCFP6pI8', 'foOG9qNShn8', '2yewlUp4BJc', 'sqglb-Lxlhg', '0WQgyelEuyw', 'wsOcVRq-aVQ', 'mO9ZKzF9EmM', 'cFpgnhCXT5k', 'o0ZQ4JCcNcU', '0FYACkEYvGs', 'BRCqQMcsORo', 'GTpbJCVNHro', 'LNfvLtfjfhY', 'uGKb6GPtLsM', 'xuG8D8oUn_8', '5DzVrXxMPDA', 'wVAxGnfgmEo', '9ttFLJ1MHfc', 'Y8Vxl6iAMZs', 'PRiNBT12Z54', 'G3aF_krvw_k', 'dLfwCjgevCs', 'l4xt9qKMPUc', 'cX4eZD3GiL0', 'ub0QVniKTmg', '7APUM1rbEg4', 'PEzoCoIolJ0', '3b7yj377ydg', 'Kyy5UOF3kyg', 'bwx9zHA1qfI', '381H8g11ZBQ', '011MdGFLScE', 'XuONqY6EObc', 'RT9NGNh0HA4', 'cfUg1In4utQ', 'UeYj4gomdEM', '1urB1PSc1GE', 'YQXZdAsKqzM', 'HdZQc9-SjCg', 'sQY6DjnBF_c', 'YNdanpN9INI', 'Pb51aSiwUEA', 'Jnsoz9eIx64', 'oUHK8E9Q8MM', 'CBGGnQbEJ0U', '3Szoh9OY61I', 'hMuxNVMFqcs', 'ZOX6-Rw5PWc', 'J_GStsHbiPM', 'I_K0_lXhXwg', 'QxKrAO5VJ4c', 'akf-m7LmPjU', '9kQUAFG6XwQ', 'nY7n9IKerag', 'CX0-AlytIXY', 'DbotJWP9zZc', 'mDjacOftSRk', 'rK3g9TGaoco', 'tKQdMnI2WhU', '08YU7wHBQ6Q', 'R6ix8CqwzNo', 'Sq4MjUNvguI', 'HW9dO2_7F-0', 'CbGozPL5BeA', '1Zh1Lfr_Ass', 'vmCPNgJaNvY', 'JirurHj37TU', 'G5JDifaDru0', 'SbCELVI-jLw', 'PrIShIfjHeM', 'hKCJxsO1jt8', '2_jD8vGlvzM', 'BvFH2QQ0fz8', 'mHJl2V1sMxc', 'JQCM81hdWOE', '0xeJ9ZklIY', 'UkYAr_wyaZU', 'D5yDKqWX1Uo', '2cT5Cg8H7ec', 'nlQ5gkg4y-I', 'dgpBuvMQ7GY', 'BRCqQMcsORo', 'ev0NkYfkgYE', 't4ONk88Xln4', 'z8zYQ2QgNwY', 'l2-BhBxnKOU', 'jeFRPBW07SA', 'RxkvXs5OO7M', '7Nu7BIJDKGQ', 'b2B5EqQfW6w', 'sEBw5sy-nj8', 'y8iRVSCwucs', 'CK0DYMeSojk', '912sLzdUs8c', '3jJo3hv1YZE', '8ReYPyizjh8', 'dD9faQ49acw', 'BvDYR-gzoKI', 'CaNRqy0C7k0', 'Xq6b0QttdLY', '_Ngx3C_bsQ0', 'Zeh9W6KKX1Y', 'Zee1YNuNSXU', 'XwyXqHSGCHQ', '7lgFhAWkI-4', 'L9v5dSRIAHc', '_8zbV_fFkYs', 'JQZNHKMcAto', '54tyrpYuBHI', 'JtR562QHTT4', 'bc_mo4bMnvs', 'V_nT8g-W9W4', 'VVEC-fslvGQ', 'yNR9TaKJybY', 'ApHTPpsPKVw', '-O65KYwuSUk', 'VifxM5I17dU', 'oHTbre5fjYM', 'Cq2YGwI-Ws0', 's7CBEtU2RS0', 'ucxJ7N_ydic', 'RT9NGNh0HA4', 'ZT7jOmxqBQI', 'KRPHf90Fi24', 'KRPHf90Fi24', 'UdvgOB-2Jk8', 'D2o9GDmnesk', 'U7oKDtytJnE', 'nWsFbP-2SQk', 'MlGi9F37lbY', '9PEowAKC6PY', 'qs-KEsse0Jk', '32nuCB9nPdA', '-AAbxW7_Frs', 'pbhmFfHpX5M', 'llNNTfbJ7Ww', 'f9QoUpskHa4', 'ddemyQkG3Ms', '-cpDIGEyew8', '97hIBu-n7vA', 'QtmqGe7740g', 'bMpQxgf1tNM', 'YI7l_5pCsQM', 'EjP13o5HQ9A', 'y2gAbWN2Dys', 'BKI1LvygvQc', 'FA-XhdWMzek', 'qnOw-Uvs6w0', 'gUD0jgnoS-8', 'fjV32vDsyWo', '4OVjNx53VHY', 'ai824t9Hw_4', 'nNB88Q4jNUg', 'yNR9TaKJybY', 'b6o3fMPMBOo', 'qhzDHHq6_EM', '8RM7BAes2GE', 'kj93ey9Pvtg', 'PGn41xbeu7U', 'crzzMD5IFZA', 'MhsqXouC1Ws', 'jREHi3XS4yU', '7dyZVSNwJV4', 'GO6JVBygYxQ', 'BXqkTC8mZ8A', '-rCTQd2bbRk', 'xzqYAS-0Dbw', 'g79_ljVC5Wk', 'B4RMDQxJSAE', 'fxmQK5LK4q0', 'tyj3T7fJcvI', 'SIUEHsyt54I', 'ssHEAOrAdCU', 'KYEj5VLHOOE', '3UtmguA4LH0', 'CBGGnQbEJ0U', '04zHT8thLZs', 'cxfMefmRHzE', 'gLei9Lgs0_o', 'YH42j9DTB-g', '5FXhbltanB0', 'eFyy2n30WBk', 'k4oquMa5LVE', 'gSt7-d9vltg', 'NTuzLY1HzZo', 'hPLE_qG8lws', 'MgkvaKe1Wes', 'Eopr3V5DGYA', '5eNik8rZigc', 'QPqbnS2XnTI', 'Yl6y6k_1X6Q', '6CEpc_m0PKU', 'AVTCzZLCT90', '25RdRdiw2Uo', '80MxOmcrqVI', 'e2rxy0xeRA8', '_HhNJnWLfeg', 'EyTzFDkC-EM', 'TX4Aa0Ajs8M', 'F9jf5y6obVQ', 'S61Xsm0nKFE', 'fpzFjnq3Z7A', 'drMczeQYIBg', 'pMP6kQPYRlU', 'SM8giITSaWY', 'eNdd54t7yqE', 'a9xN0RPIPPk', 'ID1oJGKFoYc', '7B49Jdlo7ns', 'Npta6B4EAto' );
shuffle($videolist);
$prefix = array_pop($videolist);
next($videolist);
?>
<iframe width="500" height="375" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $prefix ;?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="margin-top: 232px; margin-left: 225px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to handle this client side with javascript?

Comment: If you use a random function, it is unlikely that you have a sequence where the same video is chosen twice in a row. But if that happens ... it is still random, the user can press the random button again.
But if you want to be sure it is not select again, you should first decided how many times in a row. Will it be ok to have the random function propose: video3, video1, video3?
Or, once a movie has been watched, you don't want it to be sected at random anymore until all the movies in the original list have all been watched?

Comment: @azzurroverde Once a video has bee watched, I don't want it to be able to be selected until all videos have been viewed.

Comment: You can also use a somewhat different approach, that is quicker than shuffle. Use a random function that generates a number between 0 and 255. Chose the movie in that position in the $videolist array. After it has been watched, put it at the end of the array (swap it with the last one).
Then generate a new number, now between 0 and 254. After watching it, swap it in position 254. Then generates a new number till 253 and then swap it. And continue like that. 
Shuffling an array is more expensive that generating a random number and swapping two elements.

Comment: And when you are down to 0 with the size of the "usable" array, put the index back to 255 (pardon, 254) and continue :)

Comment: @azzurroverde I updated my question with the full code, including the whole array, and the iframe. Can you explain, in detail, exactly what I need to do? I'm very green when it comes to php.

Comment: is the array fixed or are the videos from some db?

Comment: The main problem here is to keep track of users' history. The list of movie is fixed, and the shuffle generates a new ordering each time. But if it generates the first movie, let's say 3 times in a row for 3 different users, that would be ok.
At the same time, if it generates 256 different movies for 256 different users, and then the first user comes back and it generate the same one it generated 256 times earlier, that is the one he saw earlier?
I mean, you need a way to keep track of what happens with each user.  
I don't see a way out of here.

Comment: @azzurroverde is there no way to accomplish this using multiple arrays, where array "a" is videos viewed and array "b" is videos unviewed? Also is it possible to have it so that it will only remove a video that that particular viewer has seen? (Person "a" visits the site and watches five random videos on one day, those five are removed from the possible random video's for that person only.)

Comment: I posted a solution using session variables. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['videos'])){
    $_SESSION['videos']=array('y9TAeIk1wCs', '6kApARt4Mds', '4Jgc-aolx5M', 'tHWAoKzHut8', 'USSnC-1Oq2g', 'H9rfvs-Memw', '2OMFSX3sJQw', 'Pt-EipwlWQ0', 'qxLSZFO-wTI', 'BsbpN9wXf6k', 'ztEIkFQrj28', 'AVi6eukVPOw', 'mzBCnBG_HqY', '8e9ZDYQSxG4', '6sUgC5BWU10', 'JTlFMvxj8_Q', 'uE6Z1nBqLwo', 'z3Fg_K08YIA', 'GqWn_lsjOV0', 'uF8rq8023AA', 'Pn9nXSq5p8I', 'I1zhZMN96Xw', '5X0z0uCALKU', 'KFbmYyVcaeQ', 'tl9JgWzrpT0', 'MbpqcEzzB5c', 'rykGcFPLyxA', 'X4wRgNR8QIo', 'yqGgZJcfNlQ', 'EtrkMmqv1eQ', '1v0TMGFRpgQ', 't4ONk88Xln4', '5pjjuFT6QF4', 'IZjmGDLyM9Q', 'LNfvLtfjfhY', 'qTGN0dcNhqk', '5FXhbltanB0', 'MVk7rnI8v9k', 'iyycwz_Msy0', 'F3nHEOXoh7c', 'mqFWrGKLb4E', 'bVxLB65faIY', 'ereen__ld8g', 'Kl1QO7ljUIQ', '5zkCnHUnoYY', 'nRmpgI-_a-c', 'XLsfs2YNgAE', 'AQ2ec7daCYY', 'rRstqUQhQ48', 'AleCmkfCbJ4', 'Hl8-jS26XaM', 'KFbmYyVcaeQ', 'UTDgaVL5zxw', 'GZ5paTwRA_k', 'YOSWA9OBjls', 'hutsOBSINQw', 'kAv5S-48i-E', 'n0N4yen5ilg', '_cv1zGmnoVs', '3R0ye-flA7I', 'xSJvlQqrwx4', 'DCVs532r4HY', 'DCVs532r4HY', '_dLpzmEH8nI', '1ujJ5NN5FaM', 'vbIpdBbiybM', 'JtR562QHTT4', '30-O8U4kfjk', 'BtR6IrvxeFs', 'i3i8krPi7cg', 'D5yDKqWX1Uo', 'YJzIvr5u2n0', '0xD8AE8ZcpA', '53IeDxWoWm0', 'F9RWr3fqxdg', 'iLx1I7rqo-k', 'waUk0igDAEA', 'w5fc43O3ynE', 'LHkLtLVSGVs', 'gTZPOh21q2Q', 'vDvv0dwxoYk', '6vBAwc23sD8', '8EtfOdRRxTc', 'ZzaIJfFEyN0', 'hcITGTx6SbI', '8iRoamv2qvQ', '6wj_36cm6Nc', 'u0KNXj-noHE', 'ymHZnu0L6LU', 'H8TWgOHWeig', 'U-ZiDMhFmYg', 'QjQsQXZgywA', 'maXcwJKSTCw', 'bvWw5tmQ_pw', 'r0JVZvvpU6E', '5pjjuFT6QF4', 'pbhmFfHpX5M', 'kBvR4pxNHO4', 'r5U7F0NJ1RQ', 'FrwAJWGYdqY', 'pG--yUNkdm4', 'AVj4z_k0G-s', 'wQzWAX8xJhQ', 'q8DVV3vBlzk', 'xKmPCFP6pI8', 'foOG9qNShn8', '2yewlUp4BJc', 'sqglb-Lxlhg', '0WQgyelEuyw', 'wsOcVRq-aVQ', 'mO9ZKzF9EmM', 'cFpgnhCXT5k', 'o0ZQ4JCcNcU', '0FYACkEYvGs', 'BRCqQMcsORo', 'GTpbJCVNHro', 'LNfvLtfjfhY', 'uGKb6GPtLsM', 'xuG8D8oUn_8', '5DzVrXxMPDA', 'wVAxGnfgmEo', '9ttFLJ1MHfc', 'Y8Vxl6iAMZs', 'PRiNBT12Z54', 'G3aF_krvw_k', 'dLfwCjgevCs', 'l4xt9qKMPUc', 'cX4eZD3GiL0', 'ub0QVniKTmg', '7APUM1rbEg4', 'PEzoCoIolJ0', '3b7yj377ydg', 'Kyy5UOF3kyg', 'bwx9zHA1qfI', '381H8g11ZBQ', '011MdGFLScE', 'XuONqY6EObc', 'RT9NGNh0HA4', 'cfUg1In4utQ', 'UeYj4gomdEM', '1urB1PSc1GE', 'YQXZdAsKqzM', 'HdZQc9-SjCg', 'sQY6DjnBF_c', 'YNdanpN9INI', 'Pb51aSiwUEA', 'Jnsoz9eIx64', 'oUHK8E9Q8MM', 'CBGGnQbEJ0U', '3Szoh9OY61I', 'hMuxNVMFqcs', 'ZOX6-Rw5PWc', 'J_GStsHbiPM', 'I_K0_lXhXwg', 'QxKrAO5VJ4c', 'akf-m7LmPjU', '9kQUAFG6XwQ', 'nY7n9IKerag', 'CX0-AlytIXY', 'DbotJWP9zZc', 'mDjacOftSRk', 'rK3g9TGaoco', 'tKQdMnI2WhU', '08YU7wHBQ6Q', 'R6ix8CqwzNo', 'Sq4MjUNvguI', 'HW9dO2_7F-0', 'CbGozPL5BeA', '1Zh1Lfr_Ass', 'vmCPNgJaNvY', 'JirurHj37TU', 'G5JDifaDru0', 'SbCELVI-jLw', 'PrIShIfjHeM', 'hKCJxsO1jt8', '2_jD8vGlvzM', 'BvFH2QQ0fz8', 'mHJl2V1sMxc', 'JQCM81hdWOE', '0xeJ9ZklIY', 'UkYAr_wyaZU', 'D5yDKqWX1Uo', '2cT5Cg8H7ec', 'nlQ5gkg4y-I', 'dgpBuvMQ7GY', 'BRCqQMcsORo', 'ev0NkYfkgYE', 't4ONk88Xln4', 'z8zYQ2QgNwY', 'l2-BhBxnKOU', 'jeFRPBW07SA', 'RxkvXs5OO7M', '7Nu7BIJDKGQ', 'b2B5EqQfW6w', 'sEBw5sy-nj8', 'y8iRVSCwucs', 'CK0DYMeSojk', '912sLzdUs8c', '3jJo3hv1YZE', '8ReYPyizjh8', 'dD9faQ49acw', 'BvDYR-gzoKI', 'CaNRqy0C7k0', 'Xq6b0QttdLY', '_Ngx3C_bsQ0', 'Zeh9W6KKX1Y', 'Zee1YNuNSXU', 'XwyXqHSGCHQ', '7lgFhAWkI-4', 'L9v5dSRIAHc', '_8zbV_fFkYs', 'JQZNHKMcAto', '54tyrpYuBHI', 'JtR562QHTT4', 'bc_mo4bMnvs', 'V_nT8g-W9W4', 'VVEC-fslvGQ', 'yNR9TaKJybY', 'ApHTPpsPKVw', '-O65KYwuSUk', 'VifxM5I17dU', 'oHTbre5fjYM', 'Cq2YGwI-Ws0', 's7CBEtU2RS0', 'ucxJ7N_ydic', 'RT9NGNh0HA4', 'ZT7jOmxqBQI', 'KRPHf90Fi24', 'KRPHf90Fi24', 'UdvgOB-2Jk8', 'D2o9GDmnesk', 'U7oKDtytJnE', 'nWsFbP-2SQk', 'MlGi9F37lbY', '9PEowAKC6PY', 'qs-KEsse0Jk', '32nuCB9nPdA', '-AAbxW7_Frs', 'pbhmFfHpX5M', 'llNNTfbJ7Ww', 'f9QoUpskHa4', 'ddemyQkG3Ms', '-cpDIGEyew8', '97hIBu-n7vA', 'QtmqGe7740g', 'bMpQxgf1tNM', 'YI7l_5pCsQM', 'EjP13o5HQ9A', 'y2gAbWN2Dys', 'BKI1LvygvQc', 'FA-XhdWMzek', 'qnOw-Uvs6w0', 'gUD0jgnoS-8', 'fjV32vDsyWo', '4OVjNx53VHY', 'ai824t9Hw_4', 'nNB88Q4jNUg', 'yNR9TaKJybY', 'b6o3fMPMBOo', 'qhzDHHq6_EM', '8RM7BAes2GE', 'kj93ey9Pvtg', 'PGn41xbeu7U', 'crzzMD5IFZA', 'MhsqXouC1Ws', 'jREHi3XS4yU', '7dyZVSNwJV4', 'GO6JVBygYxQ', 'BXqkTC8mZ8A', '-rCTQd2bbRk', 'xzqYAS-0Dbw', 'g79_ljVC5Wk', 'B4RMDQxJSAE', 'fxmQK5LK4q0', 'tyj3T7fJcvI', 'SIUEHsyt54I', 'ssHEAOrAdCU', 'KYEj5VLHOOE', '3UtmguA4LH0', 'CBGGnQbEJ0U', '04zHT8thLZs', 'cxfMefmRHzE', 'gLei9Lgs0_o', 'YH42j9DTB-g', '5FXhbltanB0', 'eFyy2n30WBk', 'k4oquMa5LVE', 'gSt7-d9vltg', 'NTuzLY1HzZo', 'hPLE_qG8lws', 'MgkvaKe1Wes', 'Eopr3V5DGYA', '5eNik8rZigc', 'QPqbnS2XnTI', 'Yl6y6k_1X6Q', '6CEpc_m0PKU', 'AVTCzZLCT90', '25RdRdiw2Uo', '80MxOmcrqVI', 'e2rxy0xeRA8', '_HhNJnWLfeg', 'EyTzFDkC-EM', 'TX4Aa0Ajs8M', 'F9jf5y6obVQ', 'S61Xsm0nKFE', 'fpzFjnq3Z7A', 'drMczeQYIBg', 'pMP6kQPYRlU', 'SM8giITSaWY', 'eNdd54t7yqE', 'a9xN0RPIPPk', 'ID1oJGKFoYc', '7B49Jdlo7ns', 'Npta6B4EAto' );
    $_SESSION['index']=sizeof($_SESSION['videos'])-1;
}
$videolist = $_SESSION['videos']; 
$maxIndex=$_SESSION['index'];

if($maxIndex<0){
    $maxIndex = sizeof($videolist)-1; //as suggested ky koala :)
}
$randomVideo = rand(0, $maxIndex);
$prefix = $videolist[$randomVideo];
//swap
$videolist[$randomVideo]=$videolist[$maxIndex];
$videolist[$maxIndex]=$prefix;

$_SESSION['index']=$maxIndex;
$_SESSION['videos']=$videolist;
?>

<iframe width="500" height="375" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $prefix ;?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="margin-top: 232px; margin-left: 225px;"></iframe>';
```

Comment: This is a more efficient solution than mine, I would just use the length of the original array to define the index instead of hard-coding that 255

Comment: @koala_dev what would the code look like without the hard coding of the 255? I'm not sure that 256 is the correct number of video's within that list, and I really don't want to count them all. Thank you both so much for helping me with this!

Comment: @user2730255 `$_SESSION['index'] = count($_SESSION['videos']) - 1;`

Comment: You need to substract 1 to the count to get the max index

Comment: Yes, I did it in the IDE and not here :) I updated now. Thanks.

Comment: You guys kick some serious ass. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if your array looks like this:

```
  $videolist = array('1' => 'video1','2' => 'video2');
```

after you watch the video:

```
unset($videolist[$value]);
```

Comment: @user2730255 you should add that info to your question

Comment: create 2 arrays.  $notWatched = array('1'->'video1'...) and $watched = array('219' => 'video219'); when a video is watched remove from notwatched, and move to watch?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do it in two steps...

```
$videoswatched = array(); // Create this in global area
$videolist = array('1' => 'video1','2' => 'video2');

shuffle($videolist);
$prefix = array_pop(array_diff($videolist, $videoswatched));
array_push($videoswatched, $prefix);
next($videolist);
```

Comment: a global variable is not persistent so it won't be of any help here

Comment: Well I said in global context to loop(if you are using). Why -1?